# How to put a <li> over an <ul>

Tags: html, css, menu, hover, html-lists

I'm learning to make a vertical menu using only css (I must say most of this code was copied from google).

When I put mouse over list1, items display in the back, and LargeNameList2 is over items of list1(since "LongNameList2" has a longer name) . So what i need are 1 of 2 things(or both if possible):

-How to "bring to front" list items?, so they display over LargeNameList2.

-How to make the other lists that are below(list 2 and 3) go down when I put mouse over list1?(and list3 when I mouseover list2)?

Code HTML:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">     

        #nav{
            list-style:none;
            font-weight:bold;
            margin-bottom:10px;   
            float:left;
            width:100%;    
        }
        #nav li{               
            margin-right:10px;
            position:relative;
        }
        #nav a{
            /*display:block;*/
            padding:5px;
            color:#fff;
            background:#333;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        #nav a:hover{
            color:#fff;
            background:#6b0c36;
            text-decoration:underline;
        }

       /*--- DROPDOWN ---*/
        #nav ul{
            background:#fff; /* Adding a background makes the dropdown work properly in IE7+. Make this as close to your page's background as possible (i.e. white page == white background). */
            background:rgba(255,255,255,0);/* But! Let's make the background fully transparent where we can, we don't actually want to see it if we can help it... */
            list-style:none;
            position:absolute;
            left:-9999px; /* Hide off-screen when not needed (this is more accessible than display:none;) */
        }
        #nav ul li{
            padding-top:5px; 
            float:none;
        }
        #nav ul a{
            white-space:nowrap; 
        }
        #nav li:hover ul{ 
            left:0;
        }
        #nav li:hover a{ 
            background:#6b0c36;
            text-decoration:underline;
        }
        #nav li:hover ul a{ 
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        #nav li:hover ul li a:hover{ 
            background:#333;
        }

    </style>        

</head>

<body>

    <ul id="nav">

    <li>
        <a href="#">List1›</a>
        <ul style="margin-left: 25px">
            <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>            
            <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <br />
    <br />
    <li >    
        <a href="#">LongNameList2›</a>

        <ul style="margin-left: 25px">
            <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
        </ul>

    </li>
    <br />
    <br />
    <li>    
        <a href="#">List3›</a>
        <ul style="margin-left: 25px">
           <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `position:relative` and `z-index: 101` to your `ul` to make both of those things happen:

```css
#nav li:hover ul{ 
  left:0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 101;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pj9Gd/

Answer (score 1):

Add z-index to this -

```css
    #nav li:hover ul{ 
        left:0;
        z-index:1000; // Added this line.
    }
```

`z-index` is the z coordinate of the item. Positive for nearer and negative for farther from user.